# Order fulfillment

Tags: orders, api, soap

Im at the point of setting up my Magento webstore where i need to figure out how i want to get my order information per day sent across to my logistics/warehouse team so they can fulfill the orders and ship them.

I have worked with SOAP before, so i was thinking of creating a sub domain and coding an app in which the warehouse guys can log into see the orders they need to pick that day, change the status of orders to shipped add tracking numbers etc...

Does this sound about right? is it possible to do this with the Magento SOAP API?

If so could you share some resources to get me off the ground with the SOAP API?

IF not could you suggest some other ways i could try? maybe cron jobs?

Im not really sure so any feedback is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

SOAP can be used to access Magento data via Webservice.

What exactly should be the benefit of creating an app, running on the subdomain?

Ideas regarding your question:

- If you think about creating a sub domain (on the same domain as the shop, i guess), why don't you just let the warehouse guys work directly in your webshop backend and give them limited access? That would save you time for creating an own interface for this purpose.
- Is there another software, which you use to handle the magento order data with? If so, might be interested in using the [Magento SOAP Api - Sales](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/sales.html) methods (hold, unhold, addComment, capture, addTrack, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer by Anna,

1. Since this is once daily, if the warehouse has a specific format to **import ** orders, you could give the warehouse team access to download orders daily and you could format the output so it would import right in. There are a few extensions for that, some free, that could be modified to just the right format. The warehouse team could also enter tracking numbers after shipping.
2. Another method would be to use the warehouse system API if it has one and use an observer to add the order thru their API. One extension I am using sends an email to a warehouse but that will be modified to connect to warehouse API.  I've done this with a CRM to add the order info

Also they may want to print packing lists before shipping is completed. You would need to override existing behavior.